Different geometry implies different topology for compact (locally) symmetric spaces
All spaces in this question are assumed to be connected.
It seems to me that if $ (M_1,g_1) $ and $ (M_2,g_2) $ are non-isometric, compact, symmetric spaces then the underlying manifolds $ M_1 $ and $ M_2 $ must be non-homeomorphic.
We can seek to generalize this statement in various ways.
This is certainly false if we drop the compactness assumption, for example the flat plane and the hyperbolic plane are symmetric spaces which are non-isometric but the underlying manifolds are homeomorphic.
But what if we consider locally symmetric spaces? That is, if $ (M_1,g_1) $ and $ (M_2,g_2) $ are non-isometric, compact, locally symmetric spaces then must the underlying manifolds $ M_1 $ and $ M_2 $ be non-homeomorphic?

This is certainly false for trivial reasons. Take spheres of different radii.

@TedShifrin good point is there something quick and easy I can say to rule out such trivial counterexamples? Would saying "not conformally equivalent" be better than saying "non-isometric"? That change certainly rules out your spheres of different radii counterexample

Do you know Mostow rigidity theorem?

In the last paragraph, the statement about dimension 2 is false for oriented hyperbolic surfaces of finite area. For each fixed genus, there is a whole multi-dimensional parameter space of isometry classes of hyperbolic metrics for surfaces of that genus: the Teichmüller space. All such surfaces are locally symmetric, because the hyperbolic plane, on which they are locally modeled, is symmetric. Having fixed the genus, they are all in the same homeomorphism class. No two of them representing different points of the Teichmüller space are isometric (modulo marking issues).

You're right that last paragraph about dimensions 2 was totally wrong so I just deleted it


The correct statement for compact symmetric spaces is:

Let $X$ be a compact simply connected symmetric space with the decomposition $X_1\times ...\times X_n$ into irreducible factors with the isometry group $G$. Then every $G$-invariant metric on $X$ is a product metric obtained from the original metric by constant rescaling of each factor.

For locally symmetric spaces of noncompact type one has a similar result, the Mostow Rigidity theorem:

Suppose that $M, N$ are locally symmetric spaces of dimension $\ge 3$ and of finite volume, whose universal covers are irreducible symmetric spaces of noncompact type. Then every homotopy-equivalence $f: M\to N$ is homotopic to a homothety $h: M\to N$. Here a homothety is a diffeomorphism which preserves the metric up to a constant rescaling.
There is a similar, but more complicated, statement in the case when universal covers are not irreducible. The case of surfaces is, of course, exceptional and the space of hyperbolic metrics up to homothety (even up to a conformal map) is nontrivial.
